# Without dataset or datareader how to store the database value in other object

Tags: dataset, datareader

Without using dataset or datareader, can i store the database values in some other object?. If possible please tell me..

Answer (score 0):

You are using xml file to store database value

or you have to Create Persitant Storage for storing this value.